# SQL Server 2008, developer edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Where is the SQL Analyzer?

I did a full install, I don't see it anywhere in the menus. If for some reason is just doesn't exist any more, what are some viable alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Analyzer or Query Analyzer was replace in Version 2005 with SQL Server Management Studio.

Here is the MSDN Link on Using [SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx

Comment: @Justin808: the SQL Profiler is still there

Comment: hmm. I wasn't able to find the profiler, I ended up installing an old copy of 2000 of a spare pc to get it.